# Deserialize json string to object with properties which are strings in jackson

Tags: java, jackson-databind, jackson-modules

I have a json string which looks like:
`{"a":5, "b":"asd", "c":"{\"d\":3}"}`
This can be deserialized to an object like:

```
class A {
   int a; // --> 5
   String b; // --> 'asd'
   String c; // --> '{"d":3}'
}
```

but i want it to be deserialized as:

```
class A {
   int a; // --> 5
   String b; // --> 'asd'
   MyClass c; // --> '{"d":3}'
}
```

where MyClass is:

```
class MyClass {
   int d; // --> 3
}
```

How can I achieve this in jackson during deserialization?

Comment: You'd probably have to write a custom deserializer since Jackson won't be able to parse the escaped json for `c`. Ideally you'd get rid of the escaping - why do you have that in the first place?

Comment: You could also have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54531391/how-parse-nested-escaped-json-with-jackson

Comment: as @thomas said, maybe you need change your serializer to {"a":5, "b":"asd", "c":{"d":3}} at first place.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out that I can use the jackson converter:

```
public class MyClassConverter implements Converter<String, MyClass> {

  @Override
  public MyClass convert(String value) {
    try {
      return new ObjectMapper().readValue(value, MyClass.class);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public JavaType getInputType(TypeFactory typeFactory) {
    return typeFactory.constructSimpleType(String.class, null);
  }

  @Override
  public JavaType getOutputType(TypeFactory typeFactory) {
    return typeFactory.constructSimpleType(MyClass.class, null);
  }

}
```

And in the Bean:

```
class A {
   int a; 
   String b; 

   @JsonDeserialize(converter = MyClassConverter.class)
   MyClass c; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the deserialization twice:

```
A aObject = mapper.readValue(json,A.class);
aObject.setCObject(mapper.readValue(aObject.getC(),C.class));

class A {
    int a;
    String b;
    String c;
    C cObject;
}

class C {
    int d;
}
```