# Deserializing nested JSON string using Jackson (without custom deserializer?)

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am storing an object that is built similarly to:

```java
public class MyObject {

    int portalId;
    int userId;
    Set<CustomObject> results;
}

public class CustomObject {
    int objectId;
    String objectInfo;
}
```

So when I retrieve my object from my datastore, it's returned as a Map that we can use Jackson to build to a JSON string similarly to:

```json
{
   "portalId":"123",
   "userId":"123",
   "results":"[{\"objectId\":\"123\",\"objectInfo\":\"test\"}]"
}
```

Subsequently, when I take this JSON string and try to `readValue` to `MyObject`, I get an error due to the nested JSON string for "results". I am able to circumvent this issue by creating a custom deserializer, but I am wondering if there's not a simpler solution?

Comment: as I see your `results` string is a single object, not an array as it expected according to `MyObject` having `results` defined as `Set`. Does `readValue` if you change either value to an json-array or field tipe to single object?

Comment: @gdomo Sorry, that was just poor example making on my part. In the real results, it is returned as an array but still string format as shown now.

Comment: A bit better solution: use custom [converter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63556792/8357251) instead of deseralizer